# Java Service Using JPA and EclipseLink Must Maintain Resilient Connections to PostgreSQL Database

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, connection, eclipselink

I have an issue where the connection from my Java micro-services drops when the PostgreSQL database service is restarted.

I have implemented this on an external open-source Java service (namely, Keyclaok) which has resolve dthe issue on that service:

```
<validation>
    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
    <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLExceptionSorter"/>
    <stale-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLStaleConnectionChecker"/>
</validation>
```

I'm looking to do something similar in my Java Thornttail applications, but I haven't been able to work out how. Perhaps I can edit the persistence.xml somehow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd"
             version="3.0">
    <persistence-unit name="pbm" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/***</jta-data-source>

        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.url" value="java:jboss/datasources/greydom"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-database"
                      value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.PostgreSQLPlatform"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.connection-pool.max" value="10000"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.connection-pool.wait" value="3000000"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="java:jboss/datasources/***"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Can anybody help me to update my database connection to ensure it is resilient and maintained?

Extra info

- Java 11
- JPA and EclipseLink for persistence
  PostgreSQL database

Comment: The settings shown in the persistence.xml don't seem right to me - you have configured a JTA datasource for EclipseLink to use, but also specified Eclipselink connection properties such as the driver, url and pool settings as if EclipseLink is maintaining the connection pool. And then again defined javax driver/url properties. Might want to clean them up to make it more clear that the datasource is an external object passed in and controlled, in this case it looks like JBoss. You have to use JBoss configuration to tell it how to handle database disconnects.